# Configuring kafka connect with multi brokers

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**Steps**

- I have used two kafka brokers and I have started zookeeper,kafka server and kafka connect services.
- I have one source type kafka connector which can be used for getting data from Database.
- If i start the connector[connector 1] by using the rest API, then it will hit any one kafka server [Server 1] using load balancer.After that server 1 will store and running the connector.But server 2 does not know the connector [connector 1] which is running in the server 1.

**Expectation**

- So if the kafka server 1 is down, then the another kafka server 2 should be able to run the connector in the failed kafka server 1.
- While starting the connector, kafka server should know how many connectors are in running, so that if any one broker failed to do the job then another server will be able to continue the job.

**Reality**

- Another Kafka server 2 which is not doing the job as per the requirement.

is there any thing to make it by configuration setup with kafka?.

Kindly suggest me some ideas.

Kafka Server 1

[image]

Kafka Server 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have started all processes in single pods.

You should run Kafka, Zookeeper, and Connect all as separate services in different pods.

I suggest you refer the Confluent or Strimzi sites to find Kafka Kubernetes Helm Charts / Operators

---

But to answer the question - You could give one or more broker to connect-distributed.properties `bootstrap.server` value. Then each broker is connected to as part of the Kafka cluster, and will reconnect in the event that one broker is unavailable

"Kakfa servers" (brokers) do not run Connectors

If you want to run a cluster of connect workers, you also need to setup their `rest.advertised.listener` address so that they can communicate with each other.

Comment: - I have used normal apache kafka to run the connectors
- Here I have used two kafka brokers for the high availablity  and to increase the efficiency.
- I have done some test cases like stopping any one services such as kafka connect and kafka broker.
- While stopping anyone kafka connect service, the connector worked perfectly with the another kafka connect service.
- But While stopping kafka server 1, the connectors goes UNASSIGNED STATE [verified by the Rest API]
- Expectation is like connector should be in RUNNING STATE only.
https://imgur.com/YBdB2Fy

Comment: Again, brokers do not run connectors. Sounds like one of your internal topics such as _consumer_offsets or the 3 Connect topics don't have a replication factor of 2, and the broker you stopped was the only active leader

Comment: Yes, You are right...Its working well After Changing the server properties config as shown below # The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2